# Javascript says DOM element is undefined

Tags: javascript

This javascript code is giving me this error and I think that it might be a scope problem, but am unfortunatelly not experienced enough to know what exactly is causing this.

> mainscripts.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement. (mainscripts.js:11)

```js
const needboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".needbox");

console.log("test")

for (let i = 0; i < needboxes.length; i++) {
  var box = needboxes[i]
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    box.lastChild.classList.toggle(".hidden")
  });
  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    box.lastChild.classList.toggle(".hidden")
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="needbox" id="needsuser1" onclick="toggleVisibility()">
  {% for need in needs_user1 %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  <li><a class="addnewneed hidden">Add new need</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: `box.lastChild` is defined but `box.lastChild.classList` is undefined, that means `box.lastChild` does not have a property `classList`

Comment: You should declare `box` with `let`. But even then you would get an error if the element doesn't have children. In this case though, `lastChild` probably refers to a text element which doesn't have classes. You probably want `lastElementChild`. Also, the HTML you are generating seems invalid. where is the `ul` or `ol` element?

Comment: Please replace the server code with rendered HTML in the snippet I made you - it is NOT a django related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You need `.toggle("hidden")`, not `.toggle(".hidden")`  and you need to toggle the last LI, not the anchor

But use the UL instead of all the LIs

```js
const box = document.getElementById("needsuser1");
box.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  box.lastElementChild.classList.toggle("hidden")
});
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  box.lastElementChild.classList.toggle("hidden")
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="needbox" id="needsuser1">
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><a href="">Add new need</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or more "DRY"

```js
const toggleLink = e => { box.lastElementChild.classList.toggle("hidden",e.type==="mouseleave") };

const box = document.getElementById("needsuser1");
box.addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleLink)
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleLink)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="needbox" id="needsuser1">
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'django url here' %}">{{ djangovariable }}</a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><a href="">Add new need</a></li>
</ul>
```